# protectionLevel in Android custom permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm quite new with custom permission in Android. Currently, I developed multiple android apps with a custom permission with dangerous protection level (since they're signed with different keystore and avoiding sequential install like when using normal protectionLevel).

Let's say I have app A and B. They call each other's service with their own custom permission. After some quite time, there's new app C that will use permission from B and B will use permission from C (B already set  for C'permission before C was installed). However, C can detect B's permission in app info while B can't detect C's. The only solution I find right now is by clear data app B, it will detect C's permission.

Is there any other ways in order B can detect C's permission without clear data?

Thank you. I hope my explanation is quite clear.